# How to escape a string to be passed into DecimalFormat

Tags: java

May I know how I can escape a string to be passed into decimal format?

```
// currencySymbolPrefix can be any string.
NumberFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat(currencySymbolPrefix + "#,##0.00");
```

How can I escape `currencySymbolPrefix`, so that it may contains any characters including '#', and will not be interpreted as one of the pattern.

Please do not suggest

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
final String output = currencySymbolPrefix + numberFormat.format(number);
```

as my vendor's method only accept single NumberFormat.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use apostrophes to quote:

```
String pattern = "'" + currencySymbolPrefix + "'#,##0.00";
NumberFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
```

If `currencySymbolPrefix` itself may contain apostrophes, you'd need to escape those by doubling them:

```
String pattern = "'" + currencySymbolPrefix.replace("'", "''") + "'#,##0.00";
```

Answer (score 5):

#### On quoting special characters to treat them literally

The [`DecimalFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) allows you to quote special characters to treat them literally.

> Many characters in a pattern are taken literally; they are matched during parsing and output unchanged during formatting. Special characters, on the other hand, stand for other characters, strings, or classes of characters. They must be quoted, unless noted otherwise, if they are to appear in the prefix or suffix as literals.
>
> `'` can be used to quote special characters in a prefix or suffix, for example, `"'#'#"` formats `123` to `"#123"`. To create a single quote itself, use two in a row: `"# o''clock"`.

Thus, you can write a general purpose string escaper for `DecimalFormat` like this:

```
// a general-purpose string escaper for DecimalFormat

public static String escapeDecimalFormat(String s) {
    return "'" + s.replace("'", "''") + "'";
}
```

Then you can use it in your case like this:

```
    String currencySymbolPrefix = "<'#'>";
    NumberFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat(
        escapeDecimalFormat(currencySymbolPrefix) + "#,##0.00"
    );  
    System.out.println(numberFormat.format(123456.789));
    // <'#'>123,456.79
```

---

#### On inserting currency symbols in `DecimalFormat`

It should be noted that for currency symbols, `NumberFormat` does in fact have the method [`setCurrency(Currency)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setCurrency%28java.util.Currency%29). `DecimalFormat` implements this method. If you are using one of the [ISO 4217 currencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217), you can use a [`java.util.Currency`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html) instance to `setCurrency` on a `DecimalFormat`. This will take care of the symbol mapping etc for you too.

> `¤ (\u00A4)` is the currency sign, replaced by currency symbol. If doubled, replaced by international currency symbol. If present in a pattern, the monetary decimal separator is used instead of the decimal separator.

Here's an example:

```
    NumberFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("¤#,##0.00");
    numberFormat.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("USD"));
    System.out.println(numberFormat.format(123456.789));
    // $123,456.79
```

Comment: On inserting currency symbols in DecimalFormat - My users do not want currency symbol suggested from the system. They want to specific by their own.

Comment: On quoting special characters to treat them literally - "Thus, if your currency symbol contains no quote, you can use:", so, do I have to fall back to Jon Skeet's suggestion?

Comment: @Yan: you can call it his suggestion if you want, but it's really just what the documentation says. Use single quote to escape any special characters. Double it to get a single quote itself.

Answer (score -1):

According to [documentation](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) you can use unicode.

Comment: I didn't quite get you. Can you provide an example on how the implementation?