# Add parentheses around rounded decimal place

Tags: java, decimal, rounding

I have to round a number to the third decimal place and display the number like this, 123.12(3). I need some help getting the parentheses around the third decimal place. Here is the code I have:

```
DecimalFormat reviewRound = new DecimalFormat("##0.000" );
```

Comment: What happens if you just do this: `DecimalFormat reviewRound = new DecimalFormat("##0.00(0)" );`?

Comment: It will return 0.000() with the parenthesis with nothing in them.

Comment: Ok, try `DecimalFormat reviewRound = new DecimalFormat("##0.00'('0')'" );`. From this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3540889/845632

Comment: It returns an error message, Malformed pattern "##0.00'('0')'".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is possible just with `DecimalFormat`. Here is a function I created to get you what you want.

```
public static String format(double d)
{
    DecimalFormat test = new DecimalFormat("##0.000");
    String str = test.format(d);
    String str2 = str.substring(str.length() - 1);
    str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);

    return str + '(' + str2 + ')';
}
```